# How are The Island and Hydra Island linked?

Tags: lost

It seems like Hydra Island is linked to *The* Island in some way.

> When Ben moves the island, IIRC episodes later on still include Hydra Island being close by to the The Island (I'm a bit foggy on the timeline there).  In the finale when Desmond pulls the plug and The Island starts to fall apart, so does Hydra Island where the pilot and team are trying to get the plane going.

Is the linkage between these islands ever explained in the show or in behind the scenes sources?  Are they just two peaks of a single underwater mountain that is one unit?

Comment: They're linked in heaven, where all the Lost characters meet each other.

Comment: Hydra island is linked because it is within the islands radius.

Answer (score 4):

In the [There's No Place Like Home](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/There%27s_No_Place_Like_Home,_Parts_2_&_3) 2&3 episode, Hydra Island travels in time together with the main island, so there surely is such connection.

One of the [theories](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Hydra_Island/Theories) regarding Hydra Island at Lostpedia suggests that both islands could be one somewhere in time, but were separated because of water level or other happenings. It sounds very similar to your theory about underwater mountain and it's quite probable, but I doubt it was ever confirmed by anybody from the crew.

Comment: And, of course, all islands (and all continents) are basically just bits of planet Earth tall enough to poke up through the water. It's difficult to determine where an island starts and ends, physically.